# Hystrix circuit breaker doesn't pick the application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

The Hystrx circuit breaker does not pick the values from application.yml file. I need to get the timeoutInMilliseconds, errorThresholdPercentage from the application.yml file. When I run the program, there is no impact of these properties because these are not picked up.

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Service
public class BookService {
      RestTemplate restTemplate;
      //Calling the service
     @HystrixCommand
      public String readingList(int flag) {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
         URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8090/recommended/"+flag);
        return this.restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
      }

      public String reliable(int flag) {
        return "Cloud Native Java (O'Reilly)";
      }

}
```

this is application.yml file

```
hystrix:
  command:
    reliable:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 6000
          strategy: SEMAPHORE
        circuitBreaker:
          errorThresholdPercentage: 70
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your method with @HystrixCommand() and give commandKey = "reliable".

```
@HystricCommand(commandKey="reliable")
public String reliable(int flag) {
    return "Cloud Native Java (O'Reilly)";
  }
```